# How to make diff print a full file diff when a file does not exist?

Tags: diff

I'm trying to compare files on the root file system with a backup, and I'd like the comparison to work a bit like `git` or `svn` `diff` when a file has been *added or removed* - That is, display the *full file diff*. `diff` unfortunately just prints a `No such file or directory` message, which is not very useful. I couldn't find an option for this.

The simplest workaround I could find is to parse the `diff` output and `diff -u path <(printf '')` or `diff -u <(printf '') path` depending on which path exists. That's a bit of a kludge - Probably 10 lines of code for what could be a simple `diff` option.

Another workaround is

```
diff -u <([ -e "$path1" ] && cat "$path1") <([ -e "$path2" ] && cat "$path2")
```

, but that loses the file names in the diff.

Based on [Craig Sanders's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47094/3645) and the previous workaround, I ended up with this:

```
diff -u \
    "$([ -e "$path1" ] && echo "$path1" || echo /dev/null)" \
    "$([ -e "$path2" ] && echo "$path2" || echo /dev/null)"
```

**Edit**: Turns out there *is* an option for it:

```
-N, --new-file
       treat absent files as empty
```

In other words:

```
diff -Nu "$path1" "$path2"
```

Comment: What OS/version of diff are you working with?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04, diff (GNU diffutils) 3.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With at least some versions of GNU diffutils' `diff`, you can use the `-N` flag to do that directly (although the documentation appears to say that only works for directory diffs).

```
$ ls
foo
$ cat foo
foo
$ diff -u foo bar
diff: bar: No such file or directory
$ diff -uN bar foo
--- bar 1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000000 +0100
+++ foo 2012-09-04 12:45:34.000000000 +0200
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+foo
$ diff -uN foo bar
--- foo 2012-09-04 12:45:34.000000000 +0200
+++ bar 1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000000 +0100
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-foo
$ diff -v
diff (GNU diffutils) 2.8.1
Copyright (C) 2002 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: the man page for GNU diff 3.2 says only: `-N, --new-file` `treat absent files as empty`

Comment: The version I have on hand (2.8.1) says "In directory comparison, if a file is found in only one directory, treat it as present but empty in the other directory.", so that's why I put the disclaimer. Good to know that's now documented for non-directory diffs now.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried `diff -u /dev/null filename` ?

that worked for me when i just tried it.

alternatively:

```
touch missing
diff -u missing filename
rm missing
```

Also, if you diff directories (e.g. `diff -x /path/to/backup -uN / /path/to/backup`) then diff will recursively show full diffs of all files, including missing files.  You need the `-x, --exclude=PAT` option because /path/to/backup is a subdir of /

(thanks to Mat for reminding me of the -N option)

Comment: thanks for the accept but i think Mat's answer is better.  `diff -N` seems to do exactly what you want without stuffing around with tempfiles or /dev/null, and it gives you the recursive two-directory diff that i edited out of my answer because it doesn't work properly without `-N`